# How to print a specific JSON field?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I start from a JSON string, try to convert it into a JSON object and then I try to print one specific field (for example `firstName`), but I obtain `undefined`. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

```
var string = '{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}'
var obj = JSON.stringify(string)
var json_object = JSON.parse(obj)
console.log(json_object.firstName)
console.log(json_object['firstName'])
```

Comment: Why stringify a String. JSON parse accepts a String. Not an Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `string` is string.
So you don't need to stringify that.

```js
var string = '{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}'
var json_object = JSON.parse(string)
console.log(json_object.firstName)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var string = '{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(string);
console.log(obj.firstName)
```

The object is a string, you only need to parse the JSON and print what you want. If you had created an JavaScript object, there you can use Stringify for stringifying, but it wouldn't be necessary. JSON Parse parses a String in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a string to [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), that is equivalent to pass a string object to `JSON.stringify`.

After you execute the code below, you actually got the result `'"{\\"firstName\\":\\"John\\", \\"lastName\\":\\"Doe\\"}"'` of the variable `obj`.

```js
var string = '{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}'
var obj = JSON.stringify(string)
```

At the end, use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse `'"{\\"firstName\\":\\"John\\", \\"lastName\\":\\"Doe\\"}"'` string, we will get the string object of `'{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}'`.

For detail, you can check [Autoboxing: primitive wrapper objects in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#autoboxing_primitive_wrapper_objects_in_javascript).

So, you can just remove `JSON.stringify(string)`, and pass `'{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}'` to `JSON.parse` directly.